# Swift: How to display two buttons that have been pressed on a label

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to get buttons (they are numbers) when pressed to show two digits in the label, currentChannelLabel, I created. I have been messing around with this and I can either get one number to show, or I get two of the same number to show. How do I fix my code so I get one number to show, then a second number? After this, if another button is selected, it will show the first number again and then the second. For example:

(button 1 is pressed)
currentChannelLabel: 1
(button 2 is pressed)
currentChannelLabel: 12
(button 3 is pressed)
currentChannelLabel: 3
(button 4 is pressed)
currentChannelLabel: 34

here is my code:

```
 @IBAction func channelNumbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var number = ""
    if let pressed = sender.currentTitle {
        number = "\(pressed)"
        currentChannelLabel.text = number
        if let pressed2 = sender.currentTitle{
            number += "\(pressed2)"
            currentChannelLabel.text = number
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that `pressed2` will always be equal to `pressed`, because it's not going to change within the body of the function — instead, when the second button is pressed, the function is called again.

Here's some code that should do what you want:

```swift
 @IBAction func channelNumbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let number = currentChannelLabel.text else {
        currentChannelLabel.text = sender.currentTitle
        return
    }
    currentChannelLabel = (number.count == 1 ? number : "") + (sender.currentTitle ?? "")
}
```

Comment: That last line doesn't look quite right. It will only use the previous value in `currentChannelLabel.text` when it's only 1 character. Once it is 2 characters, it will throw it away and replace it with the new button title.

Comment: @DuncanC that was deliberate — based on the examples they gave, that's what I think they want.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense. You have two nested if let statements. Either the first will fail, or both will succeed.

You need something like this:

```
@IBAction func channelNumbers(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let pressed = sender.currentTitle {
        let oldLabelText = currentChannelLabel.text ?? ""
        currentChannelLabel.text = oldLabelText + pressed
    }
}
```

The string you get in `pressed` will be the title of the button that was pressed. Then you append that to previous text from the label, and put the result back into `currentChannelLabel.text`.

(Note that storing your string in `currentChannelLabel.text` is not ideal. You should really keep a string var in your view controller, append to that, and copy that string into `currentChannelLabel.text`. (View objects should not hold state. They should display info to the user and collect input from the user.)

Comment: Oh, wait. Do you want the saved string to "roll" when the user enters a 3rd digit, so if the current label is "12" and you type a "3", the 2 shifts to the 10's place and you wind up with "23"?